# Symfony 1.4 functional test - reduce memory usage

Tags: php, memory, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a csv file that defines routes to test, and the expected status code each route should return.

I am working on a functional test that iterates over the csv file and makes a request to each route, then checks to see if the proper status code is returned.

```
$browser = new sfTestFunctional(new sfBrowser());

foreach ($routes as $route)
{
    $browser->
        get($route['path'])->

        with('response')->begin()->
            isStatusCode($route['code'])->
        end()
    ;
    print(memory_get_usage());
}

/***************  OUTPUT:  *************************

ok 1 - status code is 200
97953280# get /first_path
ok 2 - status code is 200
109607536# get /second_path
ok 3 - status code is 403
119152936# get /third_path
ok 4 - status code is 200
130283760# get /fourth_path
ok 5 - status code is 200
140082888# get /fifth_path
...

/***************************************************/
```

This continues until I get an allowed memory exhausted error.

I have increased the amount of allowed memory, which temporarily solved the problem.  That is not a permanent solution since more routes will be added to the csv file over time.

Is there a way to reduce the amount of memory this test is using?

Comment: This ticket is possibly related: http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/6621

Comment: No chance. Possible solution would be to run each route test as separate php process.

Comment: Any news ? `That said, it has been fixed in PHP 5.3. ` I have PHP 5.3 though.

Comment: Curious, what PHP version was this fixed in?  There's a number missing in Laurent's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same out of memory problem. I needed to crawl a very long list of URI (around 30K) to generate the HTML cache. Thanks to [Marek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29633399/symfony-1-4-functional-test-reduce-memory-usage#comment47442370_29633399), I tried to fork processes. There is still a little leak, but this is insignificant.

As an input, I had a text file with one line per URI. Of course you can easily adapt the following script with a CSV.

```
const NUMBER_OF_PROCESS = 4;
const SIZE_OF_GROUPS = 5;

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration);

$file = new SplFileObject(dirname(__FILE__).'/list-of-uri.txt');

while($file->valid())
{
    $count = 0;
    $uris = array();
    while($file->valid() && $count < NUMBER_OF_PROCESS * SIZE_OF_GROUPS) {
        $uris[] = trim($file->current());
        $file->next();
        $count++;
    }
    $urisGroups = array_chunk($uris, SIZE_OF_GROUPS);

    $childs = array();
    echo "---\t\t\t Forking ".sizeof($urisGroups)." process \t\t\t ---\n";
    foreach($urisGroups as $uriGroup) {
        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if($pid == -1)
            die('Could not fork');
        if(!$pid) {
            $b = new sfBrowser();
            foreach($uriGroup as $key => $uri) {
                $starttime = microtime(true);
                $b->get($uri);
                $time = microtime(true) - $starttime;
                echo 'Mem: '.memory_get_peak_usage().' - '.$time.'s - URI N°'.($key + 1).' PID '.getmypid().' - Status: '.$b->getResponse()->getStatusCode().' - URI: '.$uri."\n";
            }
            exit();
        }
        if($pid) {
            $childs[] = $pid;
        }
    }

    while(count($childs) > 0) {
        foreach($childs as $key => $pid) {
            $res = pcntl_waitpid($pid, $status, WNOHANG);

            // If the process has already exited
            if($res == -1 || $res > 0)
                unset($childs[$key]);
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

`const NUMBER_OF_PROCESS` is defining the number of parallel processes working (thus, you save time if you have a multi-core processor)

`const NUMBER_OF_PROCESS` is defining the number of URI that will be crawled by sfBrowser in each process. You can decrease it if you still have out of memory problems